# Uploading video using Youtube API using OAuth2

Tags: c#, youtube-api

I am trying to upload videos using OAuth2. But I keep getting an error like this -

```
{Google.Apis.Requests.RequestErrorUnauthorized 
[401]Errors 
[   Message[Unauthorized] Location[Authorization - header] 
Reason[youtubeSignupRequired] Domain[youtube.header]]}
```

I have my client id,secret key, access token, refresh token all set up. The token is still valid, refresh token not expired.

Here is how it looks.

```
UserCredential credential;
var token = new TokenResponse { AccessToken = accesstoken, RefreshToken = refreshToken };
using (var stream = new FileStream(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/client_id.json"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{

    credential = new UserCredential(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
    {
        ClientSecretsStream  = stream,
        //ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets { ClientId = clientID, ClientSecret = clientSecret },
        Scopes = new string[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload }
    }), "user", token);
}


var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{

    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name
});

var video = new Video();
video.Snippet = new VideoSnippet();
video.Snippet.Title = name;
video.Snippet.Description = description;
video.Snippet.Tags = new string[] { "test" };
video.Snippet.CategoryId = "22"; // See https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list
video.Status = new VideoStatus();
video.Status.PrivacyStatus = "public"; // or "private" or "public"

using (var fileStream = new FileStream(outputfile, FileMode.Open))
{
    var videosInsertRequest = youtubeService.Videos.Insert(video, "snippet,status", fileStream, "video/*");
    videosInsertRequest.ProgressChanged += videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged;
    videosInsertRequest.ResponseReceived += videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived;

    videosInsertRequest.Upload();
}
```

Comment: Is your account configured for the youtube api ?

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation and samples ? : https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/dotnet/Google.Apis.YouTube.Samples.Upload/UploadVideo.cs

Comment: @Pogrindis yep its all configured. Yeah i have seen the documentation. Its using a different method as to what I am using. I am trying to set up the credentials using Tokens

Comment: See ResumeableUpload example in https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client-samples